How does the Colorado right-to-repair law distinguish between parts pairing and DRM?
It is in the news that Colorado governor has signed a 'best in the world' right-to-repair law.  This is described as prohibiting parts pairing:

The new rule adds a complete prohibition on parts pairing technology often used to stymie repairability by requiring manufacturer consent to install new parts in a damaged device.

This is further described as:

This is the phenomenon of parts pairing, wherein your iPhone freaks out if anyone replaces a component without Apple's blessing.
"Replacing your display will remove True Tone and break Auto Brightness. A new battery will disable Battery Health. A new front camera will break Face ID, portrait mode and cinematic mode. A rear camera will only give you a warning message. And lastly, replacing the logic board will trigger all of the previous penalties," Jeffreys said, describing the practice as anti-third party repair locks.

On a practical level this sounds very like High-bandwidth Digital Content Protection (HDCP), the technology that proving digital rights management (DRM) control in HDMI, DP, DVi and other modern display equipment, including I assume iPhones.  This works by restricting how components interact such that it is supposed to not work if you connect an unauthorised display screen to your device.
How does this law handle this?  Is device pairing allowed for DRM (which would seem to include most of the components of a smartphone)?  Is HDCP banned in Colorado now?  Is it the usual answer of "it depends"?

I don't understand the equivalence you're claiming. DRM is restrictions on particular content being played (e.g. you can't play a video if you haven't purchased/rented it), not hardware combinations.

@Barmar My understanding is that HDCP in practice means that if you plug two devices together they will not work unless authorised.

That's not DRM, which is about the right to use digital content.

@Barmar From wiki: HDCP is a form of digital copy protection.  I think that is DRM in many peoples lexicon.

But what does that have to do with installing replacement parts in a device?

Because HDCP stops replacement parts working if they do not have the right key, and the algorithm requires a patent licence.

I haven't read the law, but it probably has to grandfather old devices, since manufacturers may need to redesign them to comply. So they may move the DRM into the main device rather than replaceable components.

@Barmar The point is that if you can plug any old screen into an output you can plug a recording device, making it trivial to pirate any protected stream.

The replacement screen still has to have a valid key, so it can participate in the HDCP protocol and decode the content. That's not parts pairing, because they're not restricting to specific hardware.

Yeah, which I read to mean they only differ by the uniquness of the key.  That seems a very accurate and technical feature for politicians to write into a law.

The main point is that they're thinking in terms of physical devices, not the software and data on them. You don't have to buy a screen from Apple, you can buy it from someone else. That someone else still has to purchase a DRM key.
